# Duplicates results in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `apps` table. Each app has many `conversations` and `users`. A conversation has many `messages` and each message can either belong to a `visitor` or `user` and a `visitor` can have many conversations.

For each of my conversations, I want to attach the name and avatar of the user who most recently wrote in the conversation.

If no user has replied, then instead I'd like to grab the 3 most recently created user's `avatars`, along with the name of the app, and use these instead.

This is what I've got so far, but it returns multiple results for the same conversation id, and I haven't found a solution to getting the app users avatars

```
select
        c.id,
        c.last_message,
        c.last_activity,
        coalesce(last.display_name, a.name || ' Team') as name,
        array_agg(last.avatar)
      from messages m
      left join conversations c on c.id = m.conversation_id
      left join apps a on a.id = c.app_id
      left join lateral (
          select u.id, u.display_name, u.avatar
          from users u
          where u.id = m.user_id
      ) as last on true
      where c.visitor_id = 'c6p77hu9v000a4zcth4lnefn9'
      group by c.id, last.display_name, last.avatar, a.name
      order by c.inserted_at desc
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if this solves. Recently replied means you want to get the last inserted row for that specific conversation. Did you try using MIN/MAX() for that conversation? It would be better if you show table structure and sample output.

Comment: Provide sample data within desired output and I'll be able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each of my conversations, I want to attach the name and avatar of the user who most recently wrote in the conversation.

To do that, you can use a LATERAL subquery, but you also need to add `ORDER BY` in such way that the last message is first, then use `LIMIT 1` to get only that last row. So, if I assume you have a column `message_datetime` in `message` table, which stores the date and time the message has been sent, you can use:

```
select
      c.id,
      c.last_message,
      c.last_activity,
      coalesce(last.display_name, a.name || ' Team') as name,
      last.avatar
from
    conversations c
    left join apps a on a.id = c.app_id
    left join lateral (
        select
            u.id, u.display_name, u.avatar
        from
            users u
            inner join messages m on u.id = m.user_id
        where
            c.id = m.conversation_id
        order by
            m.message_datetime desc
        limit 1
    ) as last on true
where
    c.visitor_id = 'c6p77hu9v000a4zcth4lnefn9'
order by
    c.inserted_at desc
```

> If no user has replied, then instead I'd like to grab the 3 most recently created user's avatars, along with the name of the app, and use these instead.

That is simpler, as this query is uncorrelated to the previous. Assuming your `users` have an `created_datetime` column with the date and time the user has been created, you can use the simple query:

```
select
    u.id, u.display_name, u.avatar
from
    users u
order by
    u.created_datetime desc
limit 3
```

And so you can use it as a subquery in the previous query, using `COALESCE` to control which information to use:

```
select
      c.id,
      c.last_message,
      c.last_activity,
      coalesce(last.display_name, a.name || ' Team') as name,
      coalesce(array[last.avatar], last_all.avatar) as avatar
from
    conversations c
    left join apps a on a.id = c.app_id
    left join lateral (
        select
            u.id, u.display_name, u.avatar
        from
            users u
            inner join messages m on u.id = m.user_id
        where
            c.id = m.conversation_id
        order by
            m.message_datetime desc
        limit 1
    ) as last on true
    left join (
        select
            array_agg(u.avatar) as avatar
        from
            users u
        order by
            u.created_datetime desc
        limit 3
    ) last_all on true
where
    c.visitor_id = 'c6p77hu9v000a4zcth4lnefn9'
order by
    c.inserted_at desc
```